# J2ME Storing 1500 contact informations without a database

Tags: database, blackberry, java-me

Currently I'm developing a Blackberry Application to access internal business contacts in our company. As far as I know there is no database platform for j2me or blackberry applications.
What the the best way to store large sets of data without a database?

I found http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database via google which uses a B-Tree algorithm.

Any other Ideas (besides RMS) , I should test?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the [OpenBaseMovil framework](http://www.openbasemovil.org/) or you could build up your own storing engine on top of RMS with own indexing, etc. It's a litte bit overkill, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 different ways that I know of to persist on the BlackBerry.

1. BlackBerry persistent store APIs. It doesn't provide a relational database model but it allows you to persist entire objects.
2. MIDP record store which are part of the standard MIDP spec.
3. File connection API's

You best bet is to use the persistent store api: [Storing persistent data](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-persistent-data/ta-p/442747)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is in OS 5.0, but I suspect you can't wait that long.

Sybase has SQL Anywhere for the BlackBerry that I believe runs on OS 4.1 and higher:

[SQL Anywhere Developer Edition Downloads](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1055872)